# FileInputStream and FileNotFound Exception

Tags: java, io, jasper-reports

I am trying to retrieve a jrxml file in a relative path using the following java code:

```
 String jasperFileName = "/web/WEB-INF/reports/MemberOrderListReport.jrxml";
 File report = new File(jasperFileName);
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(report);
```

However, most probably I didn't succeed in defining the relative path and get an java.io.FileNotFoundException: error during the execution.

Since I am not so experienced in Java I/O operations, I didn't solve my problem. Any helps or ideas are welcomed.

Comment: In which context is this happening? Which package/folder you are in?

Comment: You can't address resources this way. You don't know exactly where this file will be located after the web-server deploy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to treat the `jrxml` file as an object on the file-system, but that's not applicable inside a web application.

You don't know how or where your application will be deployed, so you can't point a `File` at it.

Instead you want to use `getResourceAsStream` from the `ServletContext`. Something like:

```
String resourceName = "/WEB-INF/reports/MemberOrderListReport.jrxml"
InputStream is = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
```

is what you're after.

Comment: Dear Tim, Since again I am not novice. Could you pls tell me which class to import for getServletContext() to call? Yours sincerely...

Comment: By the way, I am trying to implement in JSF :)

Comment: I'm not a JSF expert, sorry. But from what I can tell you want to do `ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();`

Answer (score 2):

You should place 'MemberOrderListReport.jrxml' in classpath, such as it being included in a jar placed in web-inf\lib or as a file in web-inf\classes.
The you can read the file using the following code:

```
 InputStream is=YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MemberOrderListReport.jrxml");
```

Comment: Dear Samarth, I don't wanna read the file, just want to retrieve.

Comment: Not sure how how you differentiate between read and retrieve. To retrieve, you have to read. getResourceAsStream returns an InputStream, which is what you were trying to achieve. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

```
String jasperFileName = "/web/WEB-INF/reports/MemberOrderListReport.jrxml";
```

Simple. You don't have a /web/WEB-INF/reports/MemoberOrderListReport.jrxml file on your computer.

You are clearly executing in a web-app environment and expecting the system to automatically resolve that in the context of the web-app container. It doesn't. That's what `getRealPath()` and friends are for.

Comment: in order to find the path should I concat getRealPath() plus jasperFileName??

Comment: @FarukPostacioglu see the Javadoc. You should call it with the filenames as a parameter. You will also probably need to trim off /web.

Answer (score 0):

check that your relative base path is that one you think is:

File f = new File("test.txt");
System.out.println(f.getAbsoluteFile());

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of problem many times, and the answer is always the same...

The problem is the file path isn't what you think it is. To figure it out, simply add this line after creating the `File`:

```
System.out.println(report.getAbsolutePath());
```

Look at the output and you immediately see what the problem is.

Comment: Dear Bohemian, Thank you for suggestion. I have known the problem before the submission of the question. It is related to misdefining of the report's absolute path. However, I want it to dynamically to be generated when I commit the file to the server, I want to not define an absolute path in the server, instead relative path. Thanks...