# How reach *.jasper files with scheduled jobs in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, jasper-reports, scheduled-tasks

I am coding a spring application. I have a scheduled job like this.

```
@Async
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 16 * * ?")
public void createReport()
{
    // argJasperPath = /WEB-INF/jasperFiles/myreport.jasper
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(argJasperPath, argReportParams, argDataSource);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, argOutputPath);
}
```

This runs at 16:00 every day and create a report. I am using *JasperReports* for generating reports. I have **myreport.jasper** file under **/WEB-INF/jasperFiles/myreport.jasper**, when I run my job while generating report I get `FileNotFound exception`.

How can I reach my *jasper* files in my scheduled method?

Comment: You can read [FileInputStream and FileNotFound Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681582/fileinputstream-and-filenotfound-exception) post

Comment: How can I use ServletContext in this method which means scheduled method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;

@Async
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 16 * * ?")
public void createReport()
{
    // argJasperPath = /WEB-INF/jasperFiles/myreport.jasper
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(context.getRealPath(argJasperPath), argReportParams, argDataSource);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, argOutputPath);
}
```

If we autowire `ServletContext` we can reach directory like this: `(context.getRealPath(argJasperPath)`